# Schengen visa entry rules for Georgia

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, turkey, georgia-country

I am an Indian Passport holder with a resident visa working in Dubai. I hold a valid Schengen multiple entry visa issued 29th July 2013 and expiring 28 July 2014. I hold US & UK long term multiple entry current visas.

**Question:** If I enter a Schengen visa recognizing country like Georgia, Turkey, or the Czech Republic before 28th July 2014 for a 10 day vacation with a return ticket, will I be allowed to travel from Dubai and enter that country?

Comment: Just for more information about Turkey, hence this comment Indian passport holders you can get e-visa at the airport for up 1 month. Therefore, you could go to Turkey anytime. 

http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa

And this is the link for e-visa https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/

Answer (score 5):

Georgia is not part of the Schengen area, however it does have special rules for valid Schengen visa holders.  According to the [Georgian ministry of foreign affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.ge/index.php?lang_id=ENG&sec_id=96):

> Foreign nationals who have a multiple entry US, EU or Schengen member
>   states visas, which have validity for one year or more and had been
>   used once at least, can enter or stay on the territory of Georgia
>   without visa up to 90 days, within the validity term of the visa.

Therefore you will not need a visa to enter Georgia in the circumstances you describe.

Turkey is also not part of the Schengen area and will require you to get a visa to enter its territory.  According to the, the rules for Indian passport holders are:

> **India:** Diplomatic passport holders are exempt from visa for their travels to Turkey up to 90 days. Ordinary, Special and Service
>   passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey. Ordinary,
>   Special and Service passport holders with a valid Schengen or OECD
>   member's visa or residence permit may get their single entry e-Visas
>   valid for one month via the website www.evisa.gov.tr, provided that
>   they meet certain conditions.

That is, you definitely will need a visa regardless of whatever other visas you have, however you may be able to get an e-visa online.  Failing that, you can always get the visa at the airport on arrival.  If you are entering Turkey by means other than air (e.g. by road from Georgia), then you will need to get a visa prior to your travel.

Czech Republic, on the other hand, is a member of Schengen area and a valid Schengen visa is required to enter Czech Republic.  As you already have one, you should be ok - provided that it was either issued by Czech Republic in the first place or you have already entered Schengen area in the past using this visa or are transiting through Czech Republic to the country that issued the visa.

**EDIT:** Where you are travelling from makes no difference on the admission policy in any country (with possibly some very rare exceptions, like Israel to Syria, for example).  What matters is your country of citizenship and the type of visa or visas you hold.

Comment: As addition, your trip must be ended before visa expires.

Comment: @MikkaRin Yes, it's stated in the quote.

Comment: +1 I'd like to add that regardless of whether the visa was issued by the Czech Republic or not, OP can directly enter the Czech Republic without the visa being used earlier *if* the visa is valid. In some cases, this may be restricted, for instance a residence permit might require registration before it can actually be used.

Comment: I am with @MikkaRin, you should really stress the fact that the visa should be valid **until the end of the trip**, at least for the Czech Republic (don't know whether Georgia or Turkey are strict about that, the quotes aren't really explicit) as it seems to be the crux of the question (cf. the date it was asked and the fact it specifically mentions July 28). The OP wasn't even asking whether Georgia or Turkey recognise Schengen visas, instead calling them “Schengen visa recognising” countries (the fact that they do is a premise of the question).

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to enter the Czech Republic or any other Schengen country for a 10-day vacation after July 18 (and not July 28!) as your visa needs to be valid *until the last day* of your stay in the Schengen area and not only on the day you enter (which is the way US visas work for example).